# WordPress Custom Post Type single-{post_type}.php not loading. Gives 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have set up a custom post type called '**work**'. I've added posts to that post-type. When I visit http://website.local/work/work-post it shows me the 404 page. I've flushed the permalinks and tried various setting changes.

This is the settings of my custom-post type:

```
name: work
label: Work
singular_label: Work
description: ""
public: true
publicly_queryable: true
show_ui: true
show_in_nav_menus: true
show_in_rest: false
rest_base: ""
has_archive: false
has_archive_string: ""
exclude_from_search: false
capability_type: post
hierarchical: false
rewrite: true
rewrite_slug: ""
rewrite_withfront: true
query_var: true
query_var_slug: ""
menu_position: ""
show_in_menu: true
show_in_menu_string: ""
menu_icon: ""
custom_supports: ""
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the rewrite slug empty?

Comment: Try this  add:  rewrite_slug:"work"; and after that update permalink.